# Prove existence of triangle with vertices in $\mathbb{Z}^2$, each angle of which is $\varepsilon$-close to $\pi/3$.

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> Let $\theta_1, \theta_2$ and $\theta_3$ angles of a triangle. Prove
> that for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a triangle with vertices
> in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $|\frac{\pi}{3}-\theta_i|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: This seems like a perfectly good approach to me!

Comment: You are basically using the continuity of the $arctan$ function to pick a rational approximation for $tan(\pi/3)$, seems very elegant to be honest...

Comment: An indirect approach:  Triangle with base $2n$ has height $h_n=\sqrt{3}n$.  Show that the set $g_n=h_nmod(1)$ is dense in the interval $[0,1]$.  To get within $\epsilon$, $g_n$ has to be within $c\epsilon$. of $0$ or $1$.

Comment: The approach is correct but a bit too specialized. You should be proving that for each $\epsilon>0$ and any Euclidean triangle with angles $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$, there is a triangle with vertices in $Z^2$ and the angles $\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3$ within $\epsilon$ from $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$ respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rather "brute force" approach. Take a big polygon $\mathcal P$ with vertices in $\mathbb R^2$ that has the angles you want, such that each edge of $\mathcal P$ has length $\geq R$. Let $\mathbf{round}(\mathcal P)$ be the polygon whose vertices are the points in $\mathbb Z^2$ nearest to the vertices of $\mathcal P$. Then the angles of $\mathbf{round}(\mathcal P)$ are within $O(1/R)$ of the angles of $\mathcal P$. But you can make $R$ arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 2):

Take the sector
$$S:=\left\{(x,y)\biggm|x>0, \ {\pi\over6}-{\epsilon\over2}<{\rm Arg}(x,y)<{\pi\over6}+{\epsilon\over2}\right\}\ ,$$
centered at the origin, and obtain $S'$ by reflecting $S$ across the $x$-axis. Since $S$ gets (unboundedly) wider when going out to the right there is a point $(x,y)\in S\cap{\mathbb Z}^2$; furthermore $(x,-y)\in S'\cap{\mathbb Z}^2$. The triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(x,y)$, $(x,-y)$ is isosceles, and has all angles $<\epsilon$ from ${\pi\over3}$.

Comment: We can take $x=x_n$, $y=y_n$, where $(x_n,y_n)$ is solution of Pell's equation $y^2-3x^2=1$. Then, we can even estimate the error $\left|\frac{\pi}{3}-\theta_i\right|<\frac{C}{x_n^2}$ for some constant. It's interesting question whether this estimate can be improved or not.